# Access Lambda logs from an asynchronous call?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'd like to run my `delete_me` function and get its output. I tried the following command:

```
aws lambda invoke \
--invocation-type Event \
--function-name delete_me \
--region us-west-2 \
--log-type Tail \
--payload '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"}' outputfile.txt
```

And got the following output:

```
{
    "StatusCode": 202
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I access the logs?

Answer (score 0):

From the [`invoke()` documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke):

```
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='string',
    InvocationType='Event'|'RequestResponse'|'DryRun',
    LogType='None'|'Tail',
    ClientContext='string',
    Payload=b'bytes'|file,
    Qualifier='string'
)
```

**Returns:**

```
{
    'StatusCode': 123,
    'FunctionError': 'string',
    'LogResult': 'string',
    'Payload': StreamingBody(),
    'ExecutedVersion': 'string'
}
```

> **Payload** (StreamingBody) --
>
> It is the JSON representation of the object returned by the Lambda function. This is present only if the invocation type is `RequestResponse`

So, add `invocationType='RequestResponse'` to your call.

Comment: Your answer changes the invocation type to synchronous, but the OP specially requested asynchronous.